# Outlook 2010 Automatic Replies

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to set my automatic replies to only send once per sender per day - I thought I had done that before but I don't see the option anymore. Do I have to make a rule?

Answer (score 0):

By default the Out of Office Assistant will only send an OOO (Out Of Office) message to a sender once per day.  Unless you toggle the OOO replies off and then on again, which in that case it resets the counter.

You would need to make a custom rule [if you wanted the opposite](https://serverfault.com/questions/125151/exchange-out-of-office-sending-an-ooo-reply-for-every-email) (a reply each time they send).